# How do I link and drag 2 Circle shapes in Raphael JS?

Tags: raphael

**For some reason i can get this working with rectangle variables but not with circles.
 At the moment, this code allows both circles to be dragged independently but not together**

Anybody know how to fix this or an alternative method?

```
addIntermediateSymbol = function()
{
    var Intermediate = raphaelReference.set();
    Intermediate.push(
        raphaelReference.circle(74, 79, 20).attr({fill: "#ff7f00",stroke: "#000000",'stroke-width': 3}),
        raphaelReference.circle(74, 79, 10).attr({fill: "#ff7f00",stroke: "#000000",'stroke-width': 4})
        );

var start = function () {
    // storing original coordinates
    this.ox = this.attr("cx");
    this.oy = this.attr("cy");
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    this.attr({cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});
},
up = function () {
    ;
};
Intermediate.drag(move, start, up);
}
```

Comment: See my example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26065925/raphael-js-circle-json

Answer (score 11):

You have to use `Intermediate` again in the drag functions (start, move, up), but with **`translate`** function (which make everybody in the set move in the same way):

```
var start = function () {
    Intermediate.oBB = Intermediate.getBBox();
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    var bb = Intermediate.getBBox();
    Intermediate.translate(Intermediate.oBB.x - bb.x + dx, Intermediate.oBB.y - bb.y + dy);
},
```

See http://irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=1&q=anglebannersoncurves#PAGETOP (click on "Draggable Set" down of the right hand side list of examples)

It seems `Intermediate.func()` is just mapping the property `func()` to the elements inside of the set (applies to `drag()` and `translate()`), like:

```
for (var shape in Intermediate) {shape.func();}
```

About monkee answer:

- As monkee points it out, in the dragging methods `this` references the clicked SVG object
- Raphael sets don't have `"cx"` as such, so `Intermediate.attr({cx:this.ox ...` is working only if all the elements of the set are *circles* and have the *same geometrical center* ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please tell me why did you subtracte bb.x and bb.y from the parameters of translate()? I know if I exclude them, things will mess up, but I am wondering about the logic behind. Thanks!

Comment: @craftsman 1st things 1st: move is fired each time the user moves the cursor. dx, dy correspond to the movement of the mouse since the original dragging position. Intermdiate.oBB.x+dx then corresponds to the current position, at end of event, and we have to launch translate to catch up with that visually. What is stored in bb.x is the position just before the last translate happens. Since translate needs to be fired with the exact delta since the previous translate, you have to substract bb.x from Intermediate.oBB.x+dx (same for y). I didn't get it in 5 seconds neither, I guess it's normal :)

Answer (score 0):

In the move function, "this" references to the clicked Raphäel object.

Instead of:

```
move = function (dx, dy) {
    this.attr({cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});
}
```

Do this:

```
move = function (dx, dy) {
    Intermediate.attr({cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});    
}
```

Bad formatted working example here: http://jsbin.com/uxege4/7/edit

Comment: and what if instead of two circles you had a circle and a text box?  how to move that?  the coordinates for the two types are different

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful js Fiddle solution that does exactly what you want, adapted from http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/additionalhelp.php?v=2#pagetop

http://jsfiddle.net/q4vUx/102/

```
var paper = Raphael('stage', 300, 300);
var r = paper.rect(50,100,30,50).attr({fill:"#FFF"}),
c = paper.circle(90,150,10).attr({fill:"#FFF"}),
t = paper.text(50, 140, "Hello");


var rr = paper.rect(200,100,30,50).attr({fill:"#FFF"}),
cc = paper.circle(240,150,10).attr({fill:"#FFF"}),
tt = paper.text(200, 140, "Hello");

var pp = paper.set(rr, cc, tt);
var p = paper.set(r, c, t);

r.set = p, c.set = p, t.set = p;
rr.set = pp, cc.set = pp, tt.set = pp;

p.newTX=0,p.newTY=0,p.fDx=0,p.fDy=0,p.tAddX,p.tAddY,p.reInitialize=false,
pp.newTX=0,pp.newTY=0,pp.fDx=0,pp.fDy=0,pp.tAddX,pp.tAddY,pp.reInitialize=false,
start = function () {

},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    var a = this.set;
    a.tAddX=dx-a.fDx,a.tAddY=dy-a.fDy,a.fDx=dx,a.fDy=dy;
    if(a.reInitialize)
    {
        a.tAddX=0,a.fDx=0,a.tAddY=0;a.fDy=0,a.reInitialize=false;
    }
    else
    {
        a.newTX+=a.tAddX,a.newTY+=a.tAddY;
        a.attr({transform: "t"+a.newTX+","+a.newTY});
    }

},
up = function () {
    this.set.reInitialize=true;
};
p.drag(move, start, up);
pp.drag(move, start, up);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into all sort of problems too regards dragging sets around.

It does:
 - extends Raphael to make dragging sets possible
 - creates new sets with a mouse click
 - keeps the dragged set within the canvas boundaries.

The code in short:

```
CANVAS_WIDTH = 250;
CANVAS_HEIGHT = 250;
var newSet = document.getElementById("newSet");
paper = Raphael('canvas', CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
var backGround = paper.rect(0,0,CANVAS_HEIGHT, CANVAS_WIDTH);
backGround.attr({fill: "lightgrey", "fill-opacity": 0.5, "stroke-width": 0});

newSet.onclick = function() {
    createNewSet();
}

createNewSet = function() {
  var mySet = paper.set();
  var rect = paper.rect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    rect.attr({fill: "red", "fill-opacity": 0.5, "stroke-width": 0});
  var bBox = rect.getBBox();  
  var text = paper.text(10, 10, "Hello");
    text.attr({fill: 'black', 'text-anchor': 'start'});

    mySet.push(rect, text);

    mySet.draggable();
    //mySet = reposText(mySet);
    mySet.max_x = CANVAS_WIDTH - bBox.width;
    mySet.min_x = 0;
    mySet.max_y = CANVAS_HEIGHT - bBox.height;
    mySet.min_y = 0;   
};

Raphael.st.draggable = function() {
  var me = this,
      lx = 0,
      ly = 0,
      ox = 0,
      oy = 0,
      moveFnc = function(dx, dy) {
        lx = dx + ox;
        ly = dy + oy;

        if (lx < me.min_x ) {
          lx = me.min_x;
        } 
        else if ( lx > me.max_x) {
          lx = me.max_x;
        }

        if ( ly < me.min_y ) {
          ly = me.min_y;
        } 
        else if ( ly > me.max_y) {
          ly = me.max_y;
        }

          me.transform('t' + lx + ',' + ly);
      },
      startFnc = function() {},
      endFnc = function() {
          ox = lx;
          oy = ly;
      };

  this.drag(moveFnc, startFnc, endFnc);
};
```

See this code in action here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/Alexis2000/mG2EL/
Good Luck!